# How can i get nodejs server data to meteor application

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have result from nodejs server and i want to display that result in meteor application.
Im getting result from sparql in nodejs

Comment: You'll need to be more specific to get some help. Can you describe your setup in more detail? Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: I have response from nodejs.i have to get that response to my meteor app and display the result.